# How can I install Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: iso

I have ISO file and how can I install Ubuntu from it on Raspberry Pi (2)? My SD card is empty.

Comment: First you need to make sure you have the correct architecture for your machine. It's ARM for Raspberry Pi, I suppose.

Comment: Everything is clearly described on official Raspberry site: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md

Comment: You need the Ubuntu Snappy Core. Desktop Ubuntu doesn't support ARM.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not supported on the original Raspberry Pi. You can use Raspian(Debian), Fedora or ArchLinux on the original or Check this [Raspberry Pi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) if you are using Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: Ubuntu is supported. ARM architecture.

Comment: @EduardoCola It is just on Raspberry Pi 2. not the original Raspberry Pi.

Comment: But the OP needs it on the Raspberry Pi 2. Read the question again.

Comment: It is been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this official Ubuntu documentation page on Raspberry Pi 2 installation:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi